# WYSIWYG HTML editor with rel=follow/nofollow

Tags: jquery, html

I'm looking for an WYSIWYG HTML editor with option to set the rel atribute in links.
Suggestions?

Comment: This can be done in most editors where one can click to edit the html code and add the rel="nofollow" in.

Comment: I'm wondering if jwysiwyg can have custom "rel" attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CKEditor has a [patch](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/4890) for it.

That said, I wouldn't choose the right WYSIWYG editor for my project based on this small feature (although CKEDitor is certainly a very good choice anyway). This is relatively easy to build into any editor.

Comment: The reason TO choose CK is that it is the only free editor out there than can effectively handle word content that is pasted in.  All other require you to "paste from word" which users for some reason just can't seem to figure out, even when trained multiple times.  Ok, rant over  :)

Answer (score 0):

[TinyMce](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/index.php) can do it as well, it's just hidden really well.

When editing a link, in tab number 4 (advanced), there's an option called "Relationship page to target". 
That’s essentially the "rel" attribute.